# Str replace php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

If I `echo $test ='test text'` it appears on my website as `<i>test text</i>`. How can I use `str_replace`, or something else, so that the output only shows the first 3 alphabets of that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo substr($test, 0, 3);
```

Substring is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
<?php

    $test = "test test";
    echo substr($test , 0, 3);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$test ='test text';
echo substr($text, 0, 3);
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo substr($test , 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
echo substr($a = 'abcdef', 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr() function as follows :

```
$test="test text";
echo substr($test,0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question a little more literally:

```
//set string to variable
$test = "test text";

// extract only the alphbet chars
$test = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $test);

//then do the substr
$test = substr($test , 0, 3);

echo $test;
```